# How can I display utf8 in powershell?

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-8

So this really has me knocking my head against the wall.  I have some XML:

```
  <trans-unit id="4" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source xml:lang="en-US">Customize Forecast (Outstanding) by Customer Detail</source>
    <target>Настроить просроченный прогноз по клиентам (подробно)</target>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="5" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
    <source xml:lang="en-US">Posting Period</source>
    <target>Период разнесения</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

I want to extract the Russian text to a file. I load the XML into [xml]$mf and do:

$mf.xliff.file.body.trans-unit.target

Trouble is that that renders as:

Ð’Ñ‹Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ð½ÐµÐ½Ð° ÑÐ¸Ð½Ñ…Ñ€Ð¾Ð½Ð¸Ð·Ð°Ñ†Ð¸Ñ ÑÐµÑ€Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð° Ð¼Ð°ÑˆÐ¸Ð½ Ð²Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð½Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ ÑÐ¿Ð¸ÑÐºÐ°
Ð¤Ð°Ð¹Ð» PDF
ÐŸÐ¾Ð»Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ CSV-ÑÐºÑÐ¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÑ‚Ð° {1}
ÐšÐ°Ñ‚ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ñ Ð±ÑŽÐ´Ð¶ÐµÑ‚Ð°
ÐŸÐ¾ÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾ÐºÐ¸
Ð’Ñ‹Ð±Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ð½Ð°Ñ ÑƒÑÐ»ÑƒÐ³Ð° FedEx Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ´ÑƒÑÐ¼Ð°Ñ‚Ñ€Ð¸Ð²Ð°ÐµÑ‚ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐºÐ¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ð½ Ð¿Ð°ÐºÐµÑ‚ Ð½Ð° Ð¾Ñ‚Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·ÐºÑƒ. Ð•ÑÐ»Ð¸ Ð·Ð°ÐºÐ°Ð· ÑÐ¾Ð´ÐµÑ€Ð¶Ð¸Ñ‚ Ð½ÐµÑÐºÐ¾Ð»Ñ
ŒÐºÐ¾ Ð¿Ð°ÐºÐµÑ‚Ð¾Ð², Ð¾Ñ„Ð¾Ñ€Ð¼Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ ÐºÐ°Ð¶Ð´Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿Ð°ÐºÐµÑ‚ ÐºÐ°Ðº Ð¾Ñ‚Ð´ÐµÐ»ÑŒÐ½ÑƒÑŽ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·ÐºÑƒ.
Ð—Ð°ÐºÑ€Ñ‹Ñ‚Ð° - Ð¿Ð¾Ñ‚ÐµÑ€ÑÐ½Ð°

Which isn't very helpful.  I've been googling this for an hour and I'm clearly missing something fairly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[xml]$mf = gc .\testxml.txt -Encoding UTF8
$mf.xliff.file.body.'trans-unit'.target | Out-File c:\path\output.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: That's it, seems I was approaching the problem from the wrong end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[xml]$mf=Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 file.xml
```